# TensorFlow equivalent of numpy .dstack()

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

Starting from a tensor `x` with shape: `(5, 5, 5)`, I'm trying to attach another tensor `y` with shape `(5, 5)` to the last dimension. What I want to get is a new `x` with shape `(5, 5, 6)`.

Doing it with numpy is pretty easy, I can just do `x = np.dstack([x, y])`. However, in TensorFlow I can't do it. Both `tf.concat()` and `tf.stack()` return error because of `x` and `y`'s different shapes.

How to do it in TensorFlow?

Comment: Functions like `np.dstack` are written python.  Read them to see how they solve the dimensions issue.

Answer (score 1):

#### with `tf.newaxis`

You can use `tf.newaxis` to effectively reshape your tensor and then use `tf.concat`

```
a = tf.zeros((5,5,5))
b = tf.ones((5,5))
tf.concat((a, b[:, :, tf.newaxis]), axis=2)
```

#### with `tf.expand_dims`

```
tf.concat((a, tf.expand_dims(b, axis=2)), axis=2)
```

both result in

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(5, 5, 6), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.]],

       [[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.]],

       [[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.]],

       [[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.]],

       [[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.]]], dtype=float32)>
```

Comment: Gosh, I love SO. Would it work also with `tf.expand_dims` instead of `tf.newaxis`?